# Is there specific install instructions, or Ubuntu version for install to a flash drive?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

What version of Ubuntu can I install onto a USB 3.0 flash drive so that I can boot directly from it and take no chance of affecting, in any way, my Windows XP/Windows 7 multi-boot (its boot sector or anything else)? I don't want grub or anything else from Linux on any of my hard drives.

Are there any install instructions, specific to doing this, that you can direct me to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can install any version you like.

You can simply use LiLi Usb Creator for Linux and load up the iso. This will install Ubuntu to your selected flash drive. You can also use persistency to save "changes" on your machine.

Lili: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
Tutorial for LiLi: http://www.howtogeek.com/65888/create-a-persistent-bootable-and-virtualized-linux-usb-drive-with-lili/

The website has a decent FAQ as well :)

Edit1:
Below is a second program which allows you to the same thing. The URL is a tutorial that does exactly what you want.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/